# Firebase Auth: How can I detect that firebase trying to auto signIn current user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` in browser to detect that user is signed in and on every page load firebase trying to signIn current user (probably based on stored token in IndexDB). I need to detect when firebase trying automatically login current, so I can show loader instead of login form.

Issue:

1. User sees login form (not touching anything)
2. firebase automatically signin this user based on last token stored in IndexDB (it takes near 1 - 1.5 seconds) **on this step I want to know about this and show loader to user**
3. User thinks that he need to fill login form
4. After 1 - 1.5 seconds, triggered `onAuthStateChanged` and login form disappears
5. User little bit confused why he saw login form for those 1 - 1.5 seconds without any loader or notification that app trying to sigin him automatically

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate, what exactly is the problem with your use of onAuthStateChanged.  Showing code is always helpful.   The callback will be invoked when the sign-in state of the user is known.

Comment: @DougStevenson added issue description, hope it will clarify what I need

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code in my app to know whether user is already signed in or not. I don't know how to do it on browser but I hope you will get little idea by this.

```
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if(user!=null){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class));
        this.finish();
    }
```