# How to detect that firebase auth is now trying to sign in user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When a page first loads on our React app / frontend, one of two cases is true:

1. Firebase auth found persisted creds and is trying to authenticate the user -- there will shortly be a callback on `onAuthStateChanged`
2. This isn't a registered user / no persisted creds found: Firebase auth is not trying to authenticate the user (they need to sign-in for the first time, or sign up), so there is **not** going to be a callback on `onAuthStateChanged`

We want to render different things in these two cases. To do this we need some way to know that Firebase Auth is actually attempting the sign-in.

How can we do this?

Simliar to [Firebase Auth: How can I detect that firebase trying to auto signIn current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420760/firebase-auth-how-can-i-detect-that-firebase-trying-to-auto-signin-current-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of knowing if Auth is attempting to sign in is through your own knowledge of how the APIs are being invoked.  There is no provided way to "spy" on the progress of the APIs.  If you're not the one invoking the APIs (for example, using Firebase UI), then all you know is what an auth state observer tells you (fully signed in or signed out).

If you've just launched the app, and Firebase is trying to refresh the user token (from having previously been signed in), you don't really have a way of knowing how that's going.  You have to wait for the first call to your observer to know if there is a user signed in or not.  Your app should wait until that first callback in order to figure out how to proceed.  The documentation doesn't really do a good job of explaining this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So there’s no way to differentiate on web app/page load between “this user is getting signed in”, and “this is not a signed-up user”? since there is no callback in the case where there’s no sign-in happening, we have no choice but to put the sign in form as the default start page. But then a second later if this is a user, it’ll auto sign in. Super glitchy UX: the sign in screen flashes by. What do others do to get around this? I feel like im missing something important.

Comment: If you are only using an auth state listener, and you are not controlling the sign-in APIs yourself, then there is no way to detect if a sign-in is in process.  If you read my answer carefully, you'll get an answer to your second question - just wait until the first callback of the auth state observer to know when your UI can first render a sign-in form.  What you show in the interim can just be a wait screen.

Comment: OK the thing I was missing is that in the case where the user isn't signed in, the `onAuthStateChanged` fires anyways - my code had an issue that prevented me from seeing that. I assure you, I was reading your replies carefully and trying to understand them, because I appreciate the time you took